# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when connecting to MySQL through Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I have been trying to connect to a MySQL server through Python, using:

```
try:
    with connect(
        host = "localhost",
        user = "root",
        password = "<password>",
    ) as connection:
        print(connection)
except Error as E:
    print(E)
```

It then throws the error:

```
1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I've tried all the solutions I can find on similar threads but none of them seem to be working and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. The password is correct and I can login with it to the MySQL Command Line Client.

Comment: i doubt that you enter root@localhost, chekc the userlist again and see if root has local host also

Comment: @nbk All the users in the mysql.user table are localhost.

Comment: This will probably help you - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38803/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user

Comment: @nnichols Unfortunately none of these solutions are relevant/useful. I've trawled through all the posts about this error I could find and as far as I can tell haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: When you login with mysql client are you using `mysql -uroot -p`? If so, it will connect using the socket. Does it work with `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p`?

Comment: @nnichols I am specifying host = localhost in the Python connector code and when I attempt logging in through cmd using the host option you stated I receive the same error.

Comment: so change localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @BerndBuffen this makes no difference, I receive the same error and from my understanding it should be equivalent anyway.

Comment: It depends on the connector. In most cases using the loopback address will cause the client to connect via tcp, as opposed to the socket. I suggest keeping root configured for use only with the local socket file and creating a new user (with lesser privileges) for your app access.

Comment: do you have special chars in the password like $ or space ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen no its only alphanumeric.

Comment: @nnichols I'm not entirely sure what you're suggesting, I've tried using a created user but it seemed to not make a difference.

Comment: you can also give the name of the socket in the array. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html  or post the mysql.user table for user root

Comment: helps this ? https://www.folkstalk.com/2022/09/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-python-sql-connect-error-with-code-examples.html

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to BerndBuffen for linking the docs which helped me figure out the issue I'm experiencing (and everyone else who tried to help).

I realised that my issue is the port default is 3306 and when configuring 3306 was in use, so I changed it to 3307. When I was trying to connect it was attempting to use the wrong port by default, adding --port 3307 solved this.